# RegEx. Is it possible to set condition relative to another element but do not match it

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Using python 3.8
I`ve got a string like that.

`**TEXT** * TEXT * *TEXT* ***TEXT*** fg**TEXT**fgh*TEXT*ghjf***TEXT***g//*TEXT*//**TEXT**//`

I need to find one last * only. Like * TEXT `*`, but not in here`***TEXT***`.

But I can not set up condition relative to this *. Conditions that I`ve got are too alike.

`(?<![*]{1})(?<=\w|\s)[*]{1}(?![*])` [does what on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azq76.png)

So,is it possible to set a regex relatively for example `*` TEXT * but then somehow change it to my case.

Comment: Perhaps like this `(?<=\w\s)\*(?!\*)` https://regex101.com/r/D7OZun/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Maybe my question was not obvious i need ALL last * if there is ```*text*```

Comment: @Thefourthbird https://ibb.co/t3FDw22 This *'s

Comment: Like this https://regex101.com/r/3Sp5nZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird much closer, but TEXT - can be a-z too and it can end with a space

Comment: You might do it like this `(?<=(?<!\*)\*\s*\w+\s*)\*(?!\*)` https://regex101.com/r/IfgrQF/1 but with the quantifiers in the lookbehind you have to use the [regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) See [demo](https://tio.run/##RY07DsIwEER7n2JxZQ8IF7REqXKDFBRukIg/KDiWEwk4vbEJEcXuPM2uZuJ7cVM45ewfcUoLpcEOL8ZmaogDfXfpAQJVKLIahO0CMnZjY91K1t3N/8MqtWLRn6cU1dCaC3AWkw@L@BYfjQ@36ziKxEV7bsrsNKSGnqGf@7ILi7Z6/ECzlDl/AA)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you very much! but can you show an example of quantifies which you are talking about. I just did n t work with pypi

Comment: I have added a [demo link](https://tio.run/##RY07DsIwEER7n2JxZQ8IF7REqXKDFBRukIg/KDiWEwk4vbEJEcXuPM2uZuJ7cVM45ewfcUoLpcEOL8ZmaogDfXfpAQJVKLIahO0CMnZjY91K1t3N/8MqtWLRn6cU1dCaC3AWkw@L@BYfjQ@36ziKxEV7bsrsNKSGnqGf@7ILi7Z6/ECzlDl/AA) in the previous comment. Using a capturing group, you could also use `(?<!\*)\*\s*\w+\s*(\*)(?!\*)` with the re module https://regex101.com/r/yCk7fF/1

Comment: Thanks , I just misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert what is directly to the left is a single `*` followed by word characters between optional whitespace chars.

Then match the `*` and assert that there is no `*` to the right.

To use a quantifier in the lookbehind assertion, you could use the [PyPy regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

```
(?<=(?<!\*)\*\s*\w+\s*)\*(?!\*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is

  - `(?<!\*)\*` A `*` not directly prepended by an `*`
  - `\s*\w+\s*` Match 1+ word chars surrounded by optional whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\*` Match the `*`
- `(?!\*)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly tot the right is not `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLGEX2/1)

Using a capturing group with the re module, you might also use:

```
(?<!\*)\*\s*\w+\s*(\*)(?!\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cpduR5/1)